# Avoid recompilation C/C++ applications in EC2 instance

Tags: c++, c, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, compilation

I want to avoid to copy and recompile C++/C applications everytime I create an EC2 instance. Is it possible to create and load environments?

Comment: Let's separate concerns. First you build your application for target platform. Then you deploy it to EC2 instance and run it there. There is no need in recompilation in the middle.

Comment: How about using Docker?